# Эмуляция нажатия правой клавишей мыши

Tags: javascript, события

В одном из тестов надо нажать правой клавишей на svg,но никак не могу добиться имитации правого щелчка мыши.
Причём click,dblclick работает, но не contextmenu.

Не работает:

```js
let element = document.querySelector("svg");
  let o = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  o.initEvents('contextmenu',true,false);
  element.dispatchEvent(o);
```

Работает:

```js
let element = document.querySelector("svg");
  let o = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  o.initEvents('dblclick',true,false);
  element.dispatchEvent(o);
```

Comment: Сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092328/how-to-simulate-right-click-in-javascript, должно помочь

мне нужно было ввести больше символов так как действует дебильное ограничение на репутацию для добавление в комент. бла бла бла.

Comment: Ограничение действует, поскольку это поле для полноценного ответа, а не комментария. Ссылки тут приветствуются только если они дополняют ответ и если ответ не потеряет смысл в случае если ссылка станет "битой"

Comment: ну когда я писал ответ, комента я еще написать не мог)